# Is it appropriate to ask for a list of common snippets / boilerplates in XCode?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I've been using XCode for a while and I'm starting to have a little collection of snippets. In XCode, they are assigned a completion shortcut and are integrated in the regular code completion, but that's probably the same in other IDE.

Cocoa example: NSC expands to `[[NSColor <#color#>Color] CGColor]`

Now I can't code without them. Is Stack Overflow the right place to share them and ask for other to share their own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ask for solutions for a specific problem (snippet), but not for a list. Lists of things don’t fit well into a Q&A concept.

Let’s say someone else is asking for such a snippet later: The answer is somewhere in the answers to your question, but the new question cannot be closed as a duplicate because … well … it is not a duplicate. And telling the user search through a long list of answers wouldn’t be very useful.